# Automate Blank Profile Creation for Outlook in TS/Citrix Environment

Tags: outlook, terminal-server, remote-desktop-services, xenapp

Basically, we don't want the Outlook wizard to appear the first time it's opened. We want a blank profile created (no e-mail support) so users can open msg files. I've not found a way to automate this process. Could anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: What version of Outlook/Office?

Comment: Office/Outlook 2010

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490647.aspx

Comment: Tried using this method, but didn't have any success as I still get the wizard when providing the blank profile. Basically, I want it to create "No E-Mail Support" profile automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the OCT and created a fake POP account. Just creating a PST didn't disable the wizard. This ended up solving the issue since no one will have e-mail access, but they do need to be open to open .MSG files.